# Non identical random numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following formula in Excel (not vba):

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,10)
```

Then I auto fill down 10 rows.  How can I re-write the formula so the numbers don't repeat.

Comment: You can't. A random number means you can't predict what the next one will be - a random number in such a tight range (1-10) is likely to have a repeated value. This question is off-topic here, anyway, since it's "(not VBA)". Voting to move to [superusers](http://superusers.com)

Comment: You may actually want a random *sort*? If you're generating the numbers randomly, you could get the same value multiple times, in a sample of this size. Or, you could make a check to see what numbers have already been selected; I think you'd need a macro for that (VBA?).

Comment: You may as well use "CELL" and get the rownumber for each row if you want to have 10 unique numbers over 10 rows...

Comment: @Ken, I agree that this question should be move to SuperUser, but realize that it doesn't have to be VBA to be here on SO.  You can have questions on worksheet-functions that are appropriate.

Comment: @Lance: How so? This site is for *programming* solutions. Excel formulas aren't programming; they're user-level functionality. If the formulas were being created programatically from macros written in VBA, they're programming. If it's about writing SQL, it's a programming question; if it's about how to install MySQL or SQL Server, it's not. Superusers is specifically designed to ask and answer user-level (non-programming related) software questions.

Comment: @Ken, Excel worksheet-functions are very often programming-syntax and development problems.  They can get quite complex.

Comment: [One Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529687/repeat-loop-until-empty-cell/5781430#5781430), [2nd Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886137/excel-concatenate-retrieve-cells-that-are-across-a-merged-key-cell/3887001#3887001).

Comment: @Lance: There are probably exceptions to everything, if you look hard enough. I suppose you could find a way to justify a question about "What's the best brand of gas for my car?" if the poster said they use the car to commute to a consulting project where they write really complex kernel device drivers. Excel formulas are a user-level question, IMO. I guess we'll have to agree to disagree - don't vote to move questions you don't think should be moved, and I'll continue to vote to move those I think should be. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a an easy way to do this with two columns. In A1, enter

```
 =RAND()
```

and fill down to A10.

In the adjacent column, enter

```
=RANK(A1,$A$1:$A$10)
```

and fill down. There is a negligible chance that of the 10 random floating point decimals (15 digits accuracy, I think), any two numbers will be the same. Thus, `RANK` will effectively always generate a random ordering of values from 1 to 10.

Comment: Since you are, in effect, using 10 random seeds (in `A1:A10`) to generate 10 numbers, the result should be just as random. Of course, the stipulation that no number is repeated in the final sequence reduces the randomness, to begin with. +1

Answer (score 0):

[This previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753063/excel-macro-random-selection-from-list/5753577#5753577) does something similar: see how `idx` array is filled in the second example.

But it requires using VBA. I don't know if you want that or if you insist on using worksheet formulas only.