# MS Excel: Unique random number generator within a range

Tags: microsoft-excel, random-number-generator

I searched for a similar question but couldn't find one..

I want to generate 10 groups out of numbers ranging from 1-60 (including both), with each and every group containing random and non-repeating numbers. How can I do this in excel?

Comment: These may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5753063/657668
http://superuser.com/q/277386/76571

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to use it

1. Open Excel & VBA editor (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>)
2. Insert the code below under `Sheet1`
3. Go back to Excel and **select your desired range** to fill with random & non-repeating numbers
4. Execute the macro (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>)

---

```
Sub randomNumbers()
    Low = Application.InputBox("Enter first valid value", Type:=1)
    High = Application.InputBox("Enter last valid value", Type:=1)
    Selection.Clear
    For Each cell In Selection.Cells
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection) = (High - Low + 1) Then Exit For
        Do
            rndNumber = Int((High - Low + 1) * Rnd() + Low)
        Loop Until Selection.Cells.Find(rndNumber, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing
        cell.Value = rndNumber
    Next
End Sub
```

[Excel file to proof](http://ge.tt/1Usp1tk/v/0)

<sup>I love those small and simple solutions so much</sup>

Comment: Its maybe possible wit Excel functions only: `=RANDBETWEEN(1,60)` and maybe an array function? But I have no clue how to check for duplicates.

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/277386/76571

Comment: Well, as you already mentioned in the comments, there's a small downside because of `MOD`. But its a good solution anyway.

Comment: I tried the above mentioned steps but while executing, 9 cells are not filled and and then it crashes..

Comment: I selected 6 x 10 cells (rows or columns) , my first value being 1 and end value being 60. A1 to F10

Comment: Your workbook is showing a flawless execution but I followed the exact same steps as given by you. What were the changes that you made?

Comment: You can click on "edited x hour ago" under my post to see a history. I changed `Selection.Cells.Find(rndNumber)` to `Selection.Cells.Find(rndNumber, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)`. I guess, everything is working for you now?

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please suggest links or books where I can learn VBA scripting for excel right from the fundamentals? I want learn it but don't know where to start..'

Comment: Start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737(v=office.14).aspx) for a beginner guide. Use [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/CatalogVBA-Excel-Access-Word.htm) if you need more infos to a specific function.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I had an answer, but this was a dead end (but quite fun) and I don't know how to remove it.
My need is to do bingo-sheets with random setups.

Make a column A4:A63 with the numbers 1 to 60. Enter a fairly big prime number less than 60 cell B1. For example '47`.

In B2 enter

> =RANDBETWEEN(1;59)

In rows B4:B63 fill with

```
=MOD(((A4+B$2)*B$1);60)+1 
=MOD(((A5+B$2)*B$1);60)+1 
...
=MOD(((A63+B$2)*B$1);60)+1
```

This will make a fairly random sequence. B$2 will only shift the sequence.